# calculating time difference from database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table `hsave_work_duration`

```
`id_login`   `id_agent`   `agent_name`   `sys_time`              `status`

28               2         hsaveadmin     2014-05-26 12:13:12     Login

28               2         hsaveadmin     2014-05-26 12:19:12     Logout
```

i want to calculate the timedifference between a login and logout of a user?

Comment: have you atleast searched about this?

Comment: Look over to the right under "Related" >>>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an `INNER JOIN` on the same table in combination with the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,s1.sys_time,s2.sys_time) AS timediff
FROM hsave_work_duration AS s1
INNER JOIN hsave_work_duration AS s2
ON 
    s1.id_login = s2.id_login AND
    s1.id_agent = s2.id_agent
WHERE agent_name = 'hsaveadmin';
```

If you have more than these 2 status, than add the following to the WHERE clause:

```
AND s1.status = 'Login'
AND s2.status = 'Logout'
```

If you want the timediff not in minutes have a look at [this section in the MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) and change the first parameter in the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function.

This can be executed with PHP (i.e. with the mysqli connector):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$query = <the sql stmt>;
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    print($row["timediff"]);
}
```

---

For further information about the SQL have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff